# Would $f(x)=(-1)^x *x$ be bijective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I wonder if I'm appropriately thinking about the possible bijectivity of $f(x) = (-1)^xx$ where f is a function from $\mathbb Z->\mathbb Z$?

I believe the function is one-to-one since it should have any $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ so long as $a_1=a_2$.
I think this should also be onto since x being any integer outputs another integer.

Any confirmations on this reasoning? Thanks!

Comment: [Here is a MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can type math symbols.

Comment: You are completely right! That last sentence, I forgot about that.  Even doing a simple horizontal line test would show that.  Bijective can only have one x for each y and vice versa.

Thank you for the link!!

Comment: Sorry; I seem to have messed up my assertion. If $x$ is an even integer, $f(x)=x$. If $x$ is an odd integer, then $f(x)=-x$; if you are taking all integerfs, that covers all integers, so you do get a bijection.

Comment: So would the horizontal line test not apply in testing bijectivity (just wondering).  What you said here is what I originally thought, but then I started thinking about the line test....

Comment: The “horizontal line test” applies, but the only horizontal lines that you need to check are the lines $y=m$ with $m$ an integer, because the codomain is just the integers.

Comment: ohhhhh.  Yep, that's absolutely right.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; for any $x \in \mathbb Z$, consider $y=x(-1)^{x}$

Now, $f(y)=x(-1)^{x}(-1)^{x(-1)^x}=x$

Comment: I think negative odd number maps to positive odd number and vice versa; positive even number maps to positive even number, and negative even number maps to negative even number

Comment: Yeah; I messed up.

Comment: Lol I got completely confused by your previous comment

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&\frac x2\in\mathbb Z\\-x,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$

In either case $f$ is bijective